# Android IBeacon Minew

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

Could some please provide basic steps or sample,code to start with Beacon(Minew) stuff in android.

I am having "Minew" beacon.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know **IBecon Minew** but you can try this lib below

An Android library that providing APIs to interact with beacons

[Android Beacon Library - Sample](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html)